# Reference request: Carathéodory-type theorem for convex hulls of closed sets

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, convexity

I'm looking for a reference for the following theorem.

> **Theorem** Let $X$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, and let $a$ be a point of its convex hull $\operatorname{conv}(X)$. Then there exist affinely independent points $x_0, \ldots, x_n \in X$ such that:
>
> - $a \in \operatorname{conv}\{x_0, \ldots, x_n\}$, and
> - the only points of $X$ in $\operatorname{conv}\{x_0, \ldots, x_n\}$ are $x_0, \ldots, x_n$ themselves.

The hypothesis that $X$ is closed can't be dropped; it's easy to find examples in $\mathbb{R}^1$ showing this.

I'm not looking for a proof of this theorem, as I already have one (thanks to my student Adrián Doña Mateo). What I want is a reference. I imagine it's known, but I've been unable to find it, including in surveys of variants of Carathéodory's theorem.

Comment: for what it worth, here is a proof (maybe for some people it is easier to remember where they have seen a proof than a theorem): take a large closed ball $B$ such that $a\in \operatorname{conv}(X\cap B)$, then consider the simplex with vertices in $X\cap B$ of minimal dimension, and for this dimension of minimal volume, containing $a$

Comment: Thanks, Fedor. This is indeed the proof I know, which my PhD student Adrián Doña Mateo came up with and told me. (That's not to say that it's not much older, of course; I expect it is.)